# Why would my MC3 Web application be making two gets with just the one action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When I check with fiddler I can see the following. That appear immediately after each other.

```
GET /C01C/Page1?_=1346588295451 HTTP/1.1
GET /C01C/Page1?_=1346588295613 HTTP/1.1
```

When I step through with the debug it only stops once at the breakpoint in my razor page.

Yet I see two requests and there are numbers after the URL. Does anyone have any clues. I can see this in fiddler and also in network tab of the IE debug panel.

Comment: I checked and everything that comes from the two requests is exactly the same.

Comment: Have you got some nested forms or maybe nested hyperlinks? Did you bind up click handler yourself? could it be it has a click handler defined twice? Si

Comment: What "action method" do you mean? Post your code.

Comment: are you using ajax post?

Comment: Do you have an image with empty src tag?  I have seen this happen in that case.  e.g. <img src="" ... />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize now that I was using an Ajax get and I had set up a ().on event. There were two of these events hanging off the same ID so it got called twice.